# OpenCV Color Segmentation Using Kmeans

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I'am trying to use threshold for segmentation color. but it's not doesn't work. how can i segmentation red and green  in this picture.

Thank

[image: this image after using Kmeans]

This image after using Kmeans

[image]

This image after Segmentation using threshold

**Mycode**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('watermelon.jpg')
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 4
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K, criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#segmentation
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshseg = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite('img_CV2_95.jpg',threshseg)
cv2.imwrite('img_CV2_94.jpg',res2)


cv2.imshow('threshseg',threshseg)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It would be really useful if you attached an unmodified input image. (And I guess you're still on OpenCV 2.4.x, given that you're calling `kmeans` with only 5 arguments? That would be useful to mention as well.)

Comment: Reshape `label` back to same width/height as `img`, then use `inRange` to create mask selecting all the pixels with given label. Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/cK8V4Hyf)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd take the advantage of the labels array and use that for segmentation.

First reshape it back to the same width/height of the input image.

```
labels = labels.reshape((img.shape[:-1]))
```

Now, let's say you want to grab all the pixels with label `2`.

```
mask = cv2.inRange(labels, 2, 2)
```

And simply use it with `cv2.bitwise_and` to mask out the rest of the image.

```
mask = np.dstack([mask]*3) # Make it 3 channel
ex_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't need to hardcode any colour ranges, so the same algorithm will work on many different images.

---

**Sample Code:**

*Note: Written for OpenCV 3.x. Users of OpenCV 2.4.x need to change the call of `cv2.kmeans` appropriately (see docs for the difference).*

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('watermelon.jpg')
Z = np.float32(img.reshape((-1,3)))

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 4
_,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(Z, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
labels = labels.reshape((img.shape[:-1]))
reduced = np.uint8(centers)[labels]

result = [np.hstack([img, reduced])]
for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    mask = cv2.inRange(labels, i, i)
    mask = np.dstack([mask]*3) # Make it 3 channel
    ex_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    ex_reduced = cv2.bitwise_and(reduced, mask)
    result.append(np.hstack([ex_img, ex_reduced]))

cv2.imwrite('watermelon_out.jpg', np.vstack(result))
```

**Sample Output:**

[image: Sample Output]

**Sample Output with different colours:**

[image: Another Sample Output]

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly you would like to seperate green and red? If that is the case you could transform the image to HSV color space and extract colors with `cv2.inRange()` and `cv2.bitwise_and()`. Note that the code is made with OpenCV 3 and Python 3.5. Hope it helps a bit. Cheers!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image and transform it to HSV color space
img = cv2.imread('watermelon.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define ranges for colors in HSV color space you wish to display

## LIGHT AND DARK GREEN
lower_green_light = np.array([20,20,50])
upper_green_light = np.array([130,150,255])

## DARK GREEN
lower_green = np.array([0, 70, 50])
upper_green = np.array([170, 180, 100])

## RED
lower_red = np.array([170, 130, 0])
upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255])

# Threshold with inRange() get only specific colors
mask_green = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
mask_green_light = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green_light, upper_green_light)
mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Perform bitwise operation with the masks and original image
res_green = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask_green)
res_green_light = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask_green_light)
res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask_red)

# Display results
cv2.imshow('red', res_red)
cv2.imshow('green', res_green)
cv2.imshow('light green', res_green_light)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]