# How to save specific color image from the output of Kmeans using python

Tags: python, k-means

I am using the below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802910/opencv-color-segmentation-using-kmeans) for color-based segmentation using K-means. In this code, each cluster is saving into one image. In my case requirement is a bit different. I want to save only blue color images. Could you please help me how can I save only blue color images?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pdb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('a.png')
Z = np.float32(img.reshape((-1,3)))

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 4
_,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(Z, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
labels = labels.reshape((img.shape[:-1]))
reduced = np.uint8(centers)[labels]

result = [np.hstack([img, reduced])]
for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    mask = cv2.inRange(labels, i, i)
    mask = np.dstack([mask]*3) # Make it 3 channel
    ex_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    ex_reduced = cv2.bitwise_and(reduced, mask)
    result.append(np.hstack([ex_img, ex_reduced]))
    pdb.set_trace()

cv2.imwrite('watermelon_out.jpg', np.vstack(result))
```

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

After using this code I am getting result link below:
[image: aa]

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: If you want only blue color image choose only the center which represents blue color cluster and plot all point in that cluster. you are plotting for all the clusters.

Comment: I know that but I am not able to implement this.

Comment: for all centers find the one closer to `(0, 255, 0)` distance wise and plot only for that center.

Comment: Could you please write the code snippet I am unable to implement this.

Comment: @RajatSingh Sorry I didn't see your code. I am applying it now. I will update you the final status. Thanks for sharing the code.

Comment: The correct rgb value for blue is `(0, 0, 255)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should only print the blue image. First find the center which is closest to blue color and then plot points only in cluster represented by that center

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pdb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('a.png')
Z = np.float32(img.reshape((-1,3)))

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 4
_,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(Z, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
labels = labels.reshape((img.shape[:-1]))
reduced = np.uint8(centers)[labels]


blue_dis = 99999999
blue_center = -1
b = (255, 50 , 0)
for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    dis = (c[0]-b[0])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2
    if dis < blue_dis:
        blue_center = i
        blue_dis = dis


    

result = [np.hstack([img, reduced])]
for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    if i!=blue_center:
        continue
    mask = cv2.inRange(labels, i, i)
    mask = np.dstack([mask]*3) # Make it 3 channel
    ex_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    ex_reduced = cv2.bitwise_and(reduced, mask)
    result.append(np.hstack([ex_img, ex_reduced]))
    pdb.set_trace()

cv2.imwrite('watermelon_out.jpg', np.vstack(result))
```

Comment: This code is working for most of the images when I am changing the value of `b = (0,255,0)` into `b = (255,0,0)`. For few images this code is NOT working properly. In that case, it is showing pink regions. Do you have any permanent solution?

Comment: i guess i have used wrong rgb value for blue color. The correct value is `(0, 0, 255)`. If you can try with this value it should work. Also the code assumes there is a blue image present in image if not it will plot one that is closest to blue color.

Comment: b=(0, 0, 255) should work but unfortunately it is not working on different images. I am trying to figuring out the issue.  b=(255, 0, 0) is working on 70% images.

Comment: can you share center values for images where `b=(0, 0, 255)` is not working. and also the image if possible. Maybe color we are looking for isn't exactly blue.

Comment: Here it is `[[2.3070952e+02 0.0000000e+00 1.9441988e+02]
 [2.5500002e+02 4.9981144e+01 1.0601993e+01]
 [2.5481796e+02 2.0063585e+02 0.0000000e+00]
 [1.2521622e-01 0.0000000e+00 2.5570515e+02]]`. All the images have same color combination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218545/discussion-between-rajat-singh-and-js541).

Comment: the default order in open cv is Blue, Green, Red or BGR so you were correct in using value `(255, 0, 0)` for blue center. But this is very dark blue , try `(255, 50, 0)` for a bit lighter  blue. Hope this helps

Comment: Great!!! Now it working properly. Thanks a lot. I am giving you 50 bounty reputation.